# How does Google's Play Store app start so quickly?

Tags: android, performance, optimization

I am trying to push the time to first draw of my app as close to 0ms as possible. Therefore I measured the current time to initial display by looking for the `Displayed: ...` line in logcat as described by the [App startup time guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#dx) and found my app at about 1.2s. Every other app I checked came in at about the same time, somewhere between 1.1 and 1.4 seconds. I would have expected at least some of them to be well optimized and start significantly quicker. Then I was really surprised that Google's Play Store app is able to display itself consistently in under 600ms.

How is the Play Store app starting so quickly (and apparently Facebook's Messenger app, too)? I have also taken care to always force stop the app via App Settings to ensure that I am measuring a cold start.

Comment: it *probably* is running in background since device startup, and only need to show the UI excluding the app start itself

Comment: I hoped I would have eliminated that possibility by force-stopping the app before measuring. Is it possible that it would have continued to run in the background regardless?

Comment: I think it's possible. In general - don't take system apps as a target, they have access to all the linux features of Android system, which normal 3rd-party apps will never gain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that I was just underestimating the effect of `release mode` compilation. Now that I tested my app in release mode, I also get sub-400ms times consistently and the observed effect seems to come from a particular focus on boot time optimization in the Play Store and Messenger apps.